# Automatic refresh a file at specific time

Tags: vba, time, refresh, call

I have a question about refreshing data in excel. How can I refresh an excel file, that is on the server (PLSQL query)  at a specific time with the computer turned off?

```
Sub MyCode2()

code()

End Sub

Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("01:00:00"), Procedure:="MyCode2"

End Sub
```

I tried this and "Call", but it doesn't work.

Comment: With the computer turned off...

Answer (score 0):

If the system is turned off, you cannot open Excel or run a macro

Have you looked into PowerAutomate?  That can do a lot of the same things as a macro (like refresh things) but on the cloud meaning no need for a PC to be on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This post was meant to be a comment, but my rep is too low to comment